# Is posible to do several insert operations at the same time in a SqLite database with multithreading? (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, sql-insert

I need to save data at the same time in a database SqLite with several threads. Is a software that store data of position of some markers and the reaction time of people in a virtual environment. I do this operations in threads, but i have a exception that say:

**The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

Are there some thing that i can i do? can do insert operations at the same time with diferents conexion?

Sqlite version is 3.35.5.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It [doesn't look like that's supported](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).  You may need to batch the inserts together or use a different database engine.

Comment: For massive amounts of data and multiple processes or threads, you should probably use a "real" SQL server engine.

Comment: Transactions and `lock` are your friends. Also, web search "c# sqlite bulk insert."

Comment: ...also (and I had completely forgotten about this) there a `SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD` flag (int value of `2`) that you need to pass to `sqlite3_config` in the SQLite.Interop.dll assembly with `DLLImport`. This is how I have done it in the past, I'm not sure if there is a native way.